# How do I maintain paint color, while cycling through wheel style, and vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, logic

I asked this question last year I think, but I wasn't prepared with a fiddle, and I didn't phrase my question as well as I could have. Regardless, I had many people offer to help, and I'm greatly appreciative. This time, I've created a fiddle, and am hoping to put you guys in a better position to help me. https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/qwuojxg0/28/

This is the full page if needed - https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/index.html - all code is on the page itself.

I'm making a mock car selector page to help me learn JavaScript, and would like the user to be able to choose car color, then wheel style. The car color should be maintained while cycling through the wheel styles, and visa-versa. I'd like the user to be able to choose a wheel style, then cycle through the colors while maintaining the selected wheel style, or choose a paint color, then cycle through the wheels.

Currently, you can select between five different wheel types, or sixteen different colors, but independently of each other, and I'm failing to come up with the JavaScript logic to tie them together.

I have every unique pictures of all 16 paint colors with all 5 wheel styles, so a total of 80 pictures.

Things I've considered/tried...

- Creating an array with all 80 image paths, and calling the appropriate one
- Create 80 image tags in HTML to get them in the DOM, set image class to display: none; then set display: block; onClick

I'm failing to generate the logic with my newbieness, and I'm stuck. Below is some of the logic I'm currently using.

```
function color1() {
  document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'images/carerra-s/color1-option1.png';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1-checked.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
  }
  
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - CAR COLOR 2 - WHITE - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  function color2() {
  document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color2-option1.png';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2-checked.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';  
  }
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - CAR COLOR 3 - YELLOW - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  function color3() {
  document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color3-option1.png';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3-checked.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
  }
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - CAR COLOR 4 - RED - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  function color4() {
  document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color4-option1.png';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4-checked.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
  }
  
  function color5() {
  document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color5-option1.png';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5-checked.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
  }

  function color6() {
  document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color6-option1.png';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6-checked.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
  }
  
  function color7() {
  document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color7-option1.png';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7-checked.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
  }
  
  function color8() {
  document.getElementById("carerra").src = 'https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color8-option1.png';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch8").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8-checked.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch1").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch2").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch3").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch4").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch5").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch6").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch7").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch9").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch10").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch11").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch12").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch13").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch14").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch15").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png");';
  document.getElementById("exterior-swatch16").style = 'background-image: url("https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png");';
  }
```

Comment: Dale - your solution is amazing. I'm doing my best to understand what you wrote.

I realized I didn't factor one aspect in my request. The checkmarks that indicate which paint and wheel option is currently selected. I have seperate images for the wheel and paint color swatches with a checkmark that use the following naming convention - "wheel1.png" and "wheel1-checked.png" for wheel styles 1-5.

Can the existing code me massaged to include this, or would it reqire a whole new approach? Sorry for the omission.

Comment: You'd be better to post this below, under Dale's answer, rather than under your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can significantly reduce the amount of code using iteration over your select-able DOM elements...

So here is your call to the site to display the car and wheels...

`<img src="https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color15-option3.png" alt="911 Carerra S" id="carerra" />`

You have a color and an option for the wheels. => `color15-option3`

All you need to do is plug in the proper index of the color and wheel here and then re-construct your SRC link to display the proper image showing your options.

We can determine the color ***index*** using dataset attribute in your HTML for the input and wheel elements.

For example, the following HTML line is the fifth line of colors avaibale so we'll give it a `data-id` of `5`:

```
<input id="exterior-swatch5" data-id="5" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
```

Add a ***dataset*** *attribute* for each *select-able* element that corresponds with the correct string needed to plug into your ***SRC*** attribute to get a proper image called back from your site.

All you have to do is create one function to handle two event listeners, one event for the ***color*** and another for the ***wheels***, each call back runs the the same function to check the ***class*** of the ***event** target*.

Then you reconstruct the `src` attribute to display the proper image you wish to display.

`document.getElementById('carerra').src = "https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color" + selectedColor + "-option" + wheelOption + ".png";`

Note: You will need to retrieve the default setting for color and wheel in your HTML, this can be done using a couple of `.split` functions on the default src string. We define each ***default*** wheel and ***color*** using this method, then we plug them in each time the click event is triggered using a conditional.

```js
const swatch = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch')
const wheels = document.querySelectorAll('.wheels')
const car = document.getElementById('carerra')

function getOptions(e) {
  const selected = e.target;
  let defaultColor = car.src.split('color')
  let defColor = defaultColor[1].split('-')[0]

  let defaultWheel = car.src.split('option')
  let defWheel = defaultWheel[1].split('.')[0]
   
   // conditional to check color
   e.target.classList.contains('swatch') ?
    //this is the color event
    defColor = e.target.dataset.id : null

   // conditional to check wheel
   e.target.classList.contains('wheels') ?
    //this is the wheel event
    defWheel = e.target.dataset.id : null
    
  document.getElementById('carerra').src = `https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color${defColor}-option${defWheel}.png`;
}

swatch.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('click', getOptions)
})

wheels.forEach(wheel => {
  wheel.addEventListener('click', getOptions)
})

// this could be reduced down to => window.addEventListener('click', getOptions) 
// as there is a conditional to check the evnet classList and will only fire in 
// the conditional there is the proper class contained within the element
```

```css
.swatch {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* background-image: url(images/checkmark.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 100% 100%;*/
}

.swatch:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #d7d4d4;
}

.swatch:active,
.swatch:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ff0000;
}

#exterior-swatch1 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch2 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch3 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color3.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch4 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color4.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch5 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color5.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch6 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color6.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch7 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color7.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch8 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color8.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch9 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color9.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch10 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color10.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch11 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color11.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch12 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color12.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch13 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color13.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch14 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color14.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch15 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color15.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#exterior-swatch16 {
  background-image: url(https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/swatches/exterior/exterior-color16.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.wheels {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#carerra {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="example4">
  <li class="active">
    <h3 class="accord">Exterior Colors</h3>
    <div class="panel loading">
      <h5 class="option-subhead">Standard Colors</h5>
      <input id="exterior-swatch1" data-id="1" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch2" data-id="2" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch3" data-id="3" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch4" data-id="4" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <h5 class="option-subhead">Metallic Colors</h5>
      <input id="exterior-swatch5" data-id="5" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch6" data-id="6" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch7" data-id="7" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch8" data-id="8" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" /><br>
      <input id="exterior-swatch9" data-id="9" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch10" data-id="10" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch11" data-id="11" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch12" data-id="12" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <h5 class="option-subhead">Special Colors</h5>
      <input id="exterior-swatch13" data-id="13" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch14" data-id="14" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch15" data-id="15" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
      <input id="exterior-swatch16" data-id="16" type="button" value=" " class="swatch" />
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h3 class="accord">Wheel Options</h3>
    <div class="panel loading">
      <img src="https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel1.png" alt="Wheel Option 1" id="wheel1" data-id="1" class="wheels" />
      <img src="https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel2.png" alt="Wheel Option 2" id="wheel2" data-id="2" class="wheels" />
      <img src="https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel3.png" alt="Wheel Option 3" id="wheel3" data-id="3" class="wheels" />
      <img src="https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel4.png" alt="Wheel Option 4" id="wheel4" data-id="4" class="wheels" />
      <img src="https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/wheels/wheel5.png" alt="Wheel Option 5" id="wheel5" data-id="5" class="wheels" />
    </div>
  </li>

  <div id="car">
    <img src="https://www.sanjosecoder.com/porsche-working/images/carerra-s/color1-option1.png" alt="911 Carerra S" id="carerra" />
  </div>
```

Here is your fiddle with the code listed above...
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57xu3m2w/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Dale. I knew before I started there is a more efficient way to code this, I just don't know how to do it. I started with what I could figure out. I have much to learn. Please allow me some time to understand and implement your response, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I see the solution your wrote is so clean and efficient. It's amazing. It's a little over my head, so I'm going to have to study what you wrote to try to understand it, but the code works beautifully. Thank you Dale, you do incredible work.

Comment: Dale - your solution is amazing. I'm doing my best to understand what you wrote. I realized I didn't factor one aspect in my request. The checkmarks that indicate which paint and wheel option is currently selected. I have seperate images for the wheel and paint color swatches with a checkmark that use the following naming convention - "wheel1.png" and "wheel1-checked.png" for wheel styles 1-5. Can the existing code me massaged to include this, or would it reqire a whole new approach? Sorry for the omission.

Comment: Update your question with the HTML checkboxes and a section entitled update, with a brief description of any info you feel I made need to further assist and I will take a look ;)

Comment: Okay thanks Dale. There is detail I'd like to get working again. I failed to mention it as a criteria, as I didn't want to ask too much at once.

I think I'll need to make a new fiddle for this when I can, but when the paint color or wheel option is selected, I had a red checkmark to indicate the current selection was active, and I didn't list that as one of the objectives. I have the graphics, and had it working at one point, but it was months ago and I fogot what I did. lol

I'll make another fiddle soon - thank you Dale.

Comment: NP bud, just let me know in this thread and link to your Fiddle and Ill take a look, best...

Comment: BTW, I see I'm making some mistakes on the forum...I'll try to do better with adhearing to the guidelines...

Comment: ** UPDATE FEB 11 2023 ** Fiddle 1: Is my old clunky code that displays the checkboxes according to selction, maintians selection, but defaults back to the black paint on each new wheel selection. jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/qwuojxg0/52 Fiddle 2: Your modern, sleek code that solved my previous problem efficiently, but missing the checkmark feature. jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/yoc0stn1/20 I tried to study your code and modify on my own, but way over my head. :o)

Comment: Ok so your looking for a ***red check mark*** ☑ directly to the right of the *selected* option for both ***color*** and ***wheel*** options, yes?

Comment: Yeah, just a check mark to indicate it's the selected option.

Comment: Think you're looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6jhf70sy/) yes

Comment: I added a method to handle the checkmark for you https://jsfiddle.net/dqcLt5gb/

Comment: Yes sir Dale, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Awesome! :o)